# Run PowerShell over Kudu Command API to Edit Files

Tags: powershell, azure, cmd, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I need to modify the contents of files of my Azure Web App such as the Web.config and text files. Using the Kudu command line API I am able to create a directory or deal with objects using something like the following:

```
$username = "`$myuser"
$password = "mypass"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))   
$apiUrl = "https://mywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"

$commandBody = @{
    command = "md D:\home\site\wwwroot\newDirectory"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $commandBody) | Out-Null
```

How can I modify files via the Kudu Command API? My ideal state would be to execute PowerShell over the command line API using something like the following:

```
powershell -Command "(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File myFile.txt"
```

The above command works when I enter this in the CMD Debug Console of the Kudu interface, but I need to call this over the API. I tried the following:

```
$username = "`$myuser"
$password = "mypass"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$password)))   
$apiUrl = "https://mywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"

$commandBody = @{
    command = powershell.exe -command "(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File myFile.txt"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $commandBody) | Out-Null
```

However, it doesn't edit the file and instead throws an error of:

> Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't look right:

```
command = powershell.exe -command "(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File myFile.txt"
```

Are you trying to run this powershell command client side or Kudu side? I'm guessing Kudu, in which case you will need to escape it. e.g.

```
command = "powershell.exe -command `"(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File myFile.txt`""
```

Comment: I tired the second option via the API, but it doesn't change the value of foo to bar. It works using powershell.exe -command "(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File myFile.txt" from the CMD Debug Console. Does the Command API support calling PowerShell? Maybe I need to declare the path to the file better (ex. D:\home\site\wwwroot\myFile.txt)

Comment: It was the path. It needed to be: command = "powershell -command `"(gc D:\home\site\wwwroot\myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File D:\home\site\wwwroot\myFile.txt`""

Comment: Hi How to update the json file ? i just want to update the matching url

Comment: @DavidEbbo - How to update json [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77750224/8505315)